# Change UIDatePicker selected Date text Color for Dark mode (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, ios13, ios-darkmode

Having trouble to find out a solution for changing the color of text for the selected Date in iOS 13 dark mode.

I know how to change the color of the text of a UIPicker view using code

```
self.timePicker.setValue(UIColor.black, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

OR using User Defined Runtime Attributes. But nothing is working for changing the selected date color for iOS 13 Dark mode. With background white color and black text color, my date picker-view looks like this:

[image]

So with changing the text color black, does not change the selected date text color. It changes all the other text color to black; but not the selected one. Selected one stays white, which is default for dark mode.

Comment: Use `UIColor.label`, not `UIColor.black`.

Comment: Sorry didn't get it. Why would I use label? I am change the color. Should I mention the color as value for the keyfield 'textColor' ?

Comment: Try what I stated. `label` is a color.

Comment: Don't change the color in code! Set all colors in Interface Builder to `default`

Comment: Well, the problem is that, our app background color is dark gray. So i use the default mode, it will bring the text color to white with clear background. So we wanted to keep it same for both dark and normal mode, which is black text color with white background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS13 White Color issue with textColor of UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985583/ios13-white-color-issue-with-textcolor-of-uikit)

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985583/ios13-white-color-issue-with-textcolor-of-uikit/57985965#57985965

Comment: The "label" color doesn't solve it. UIDatePicker ignores both the background-color and "tint" settings. If your app has a dark background, date pickers are illegible in Light mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found something that solves the problem in a way. If I mark 'hightlightsToday' color to false, then the selected text shows with the color you set your code.

```
self.datePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

But if I wanted to highlight my selected date text color with a different color; in that case not sure which key value I have to change. So I am going to leave the question open, incase anyone knows how to change the selected date text color for dark mode.

Answer (score 13):

You can set `self.window` inside `AppDelegate.m` and override Interface style like so

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
}
return YES;
```

Swift 5.*

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    self.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

Comment: This also makes embedded maps use the light color scheme when they should be using the dark one.

Answer (score 6):

You can resolve this problem via Info.plist file. Add "UIUserInterfaceStyle" key and "Light" value in Info.plist file.

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Reference: https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker/issues/365#issuecomment-532875809

Answer (score 3):

You can write an extension for UIDatePicker and then set the textColor of the datePicker text to UIColor.label, it will dynamically change according to the interface mode(light/dark mode).

```
extension UIDatePicker {

     var textColor: UIColor? {
         set {
              setValue(newValue, forKeyPath: "textColor")
             }
         get {
              return value(forKeyPath: "textColor") as? UIColor
             }
     }  

     var highlightsToday : Bool? {
         set {
              setValue(newValue, forKeyPath: "highlightsToday")
             }
         get {
              return value(forKey: "highlightsToday") as? Bool
             }
     }      
 }
```

After this, you can set the textColor value like:-

```
  let datePicker = UIDatePicker()  
  datePicker.textColor = UIColor.label
```

Comment: For Obj-C. this worked for me:
[self.datePicker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];